# Программное создание групп элементов в wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте, прошу помощи. Есть WrapPanel, в котором располагается импровизированная рамка из гридов. Необходимо по нажатию кнопки создать 50 таких рамок. Как это можно сделать?

(Если это можно реализовать более человеческим путем, а не как у меня, то поправьте, пожалуйста.)

```
<WrapPanel Name="images">
    <Grid Name="borderGrid" Background="#3d4657" Width="200" Margin="5">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="198"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="179"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Name="backgroundGrid" Background="#1d242f" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
            <Image Name="img" Width="200" MouseLeftButtonUp="imageClick"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</WrapPanel>
```

Comment: Используйте `ItemsControl` с `ItemTemplate` и привязку к коллекции с 50ю элементами

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поясню, что имел в виду @Андрей.

При помощи `ItemsControl` можно отобразить множество элементов, задаваемых в VM. Для этого используется такая конструкция:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Background="#3d4657" Width="200" Margin="5">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="198"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="179"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid Background="#1d242f" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
                    <Image Width="200" MouseLeftButtonUp="imageClick"
                           Source="{Binding Source}"/>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

`ItemsSource` указывает, откуда брать описания для изображения, `ItemsPanel` — как располагать размещать изображения, а `ItemTemplate` — как отображать один элемент в соответствии с его описанием.

В code-behind вам нужно просто в `DataContext` «доставить» коллекцию из 50 объектов, описывающих картинку. Например, это могут быть объекты такого класса:

```
class ImageDesc
{
    public string Source { get; }
    // остальные данные тут
}
```